# Debugging kext with gdb: deadlock

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, kernel, kernel-extension

I have I/O Kit driver: virtual ethernet device. After some period of work OS hangs, so looks like I have some deadlock in my driver.
I've done next steps:

 - connect two macbooks via FireWire

 - set up debugging environment

 - initialise NMI (via power button)

 - connect to the target via gdb

 - grab address of my kext

 - create and load symbols (this is the last point in all docs I've read)

 So far so good. In case of kernel panic it would be enough. **But** in my case there is no kernel panic and I reside in the thread that handle the NMI.
Now the question: how can I switch to the thread of my kext?
Command `showalltasks` gives me listing of all tasks, the only task where my kext may be running is kernel_task, so I'm trying to examine this task via `showtaskthreads` and `showtaskstacks` but can't find anything similar to my code. Am I missing something?

I would be appreciated for any suggestions or links to the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm answering my own question.
To see the thread using code of my kext I need to switch to the process using my kext. In my case it will be probably a browser (since my kext is the NKE).
But in fact it didn't help me a lot. But old print method helped me to find the deadlock. So my advice is next: for the kernel panic - use debugger, for the deadlock - use printing, find place where lock is and analyse code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering your question directly - but would it be possible to hit your kext code with a breakpoint?  A common method of kernel debugging is to nmi the machine, attach the debugger, put a breakpoint in the code of interest, resume execution (`continue`) and then do whatever is needed to hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it will not help: after deadlock I can't continue execution, before... well, usually it works fine about hour or two so it is not the case too